# Easy way to calculate total height of rows having different row heights

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I have a worksheet (Excel 2010) in which I want to delete 14 rows having different row heights, but after deleting I want to increase one row by the total height of the 14 deleted rows so that all my worksheets, when printed, will look alike, i.e. font size-wise.  For example, if all my 14 rows have the same row height, it is easy for me to calculate the total height ( say 14 X 5 = 70) but my 14 rows have different heights.  To find out each row's height and add it to get the total height of 14 rows is tedious.  Is there a formula or a shortcut to achieve this?  PLEASE HELP ME.

Comment: Would it be possible to use a different approach, like deleting the contents and leaving the original rows in place?  (You could merge cells to simulate a single row if that is important.)

Answer (score 0):

If you can use VBA

```
Range("A1:A14").Height
```

Put this in some event of your sheet and it can be used to print or show in some cell, you can also automate the entire task if you want it to be performed repeatedly